# Drag and Drop functionality overlaps in disclosure Panel

Tags: gwt, drag-and-drop

I am trying to add Drag and Drop functionality to Disclosure Panel using `DraggableWidget` as follows.

```
 DraggableWidget<DisclosurePanel> draggableWiget = 
     new DraggableWidget<DisclosurePanel>( pnlDisclosure[j] );
```

This is working fine for me but when I drop the widget onto another widget its getting overlapped.

How do i prevent from the overlapping ?

Any Help will be appreciated.